# Merge update violates UK

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, unique-key

I've seen a lot of posts and none of them explain my issue. Sorry if I missed this elsewhere.

I have a merge statement The tables are:

```
table1 (field1, field2, field3)
```

and:

```
table2 (PK, fieldA, fieldB, fieldC, fieldD) Unique Key = (FieldA, FieldB, FieldD)
```

The merge statement is as such:

```
merge into table2 WITH (HOLDLOCK) as T2
using (select * from table1) as T1
on field1 = fieldA and field3 = fieldC
when matched then update set
fieldB = field2
```

The records in question are:

```
table1

1, 2, 3

4, 5, 6

table2

0, 1, 2, 3, null

1, 7, 8, 9, null
```

The error I get is that I can't insert a duplicate record due to the UK. Duplicate values are (1, 2, null)

So I'm just **updating** a field to be **exactly what it was**, yet I get a UK constraint error. What gives?

Comment: Your merge statement has a syntax error, and even with that syntax error fixed, it attempts to update `field2` in a table where no such column exists. Without a *real* sample to demonstrate the problem, this question will likely not get a good answer.

Comment: I'll fix it. Sorry. Thanks. What is the syntax error?

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you working on? I [tried the above situation](http://rextester.com/XOM99877) and I didn't get any issues on SQL Server 2014 (the Rextester backend) and SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Maybe it's a safe assumption, but worth checking: was Table2 internally consistent ab initio?  In other words, when the pre-existing records were inserted, were constraints checked?  When you try to merge now, it's checking the constraints, and complaining, and the assumption is that the merge itself is bad, but that assumption may not be accurate.

Comment: I believe 2016 and we just went to compatibility mode 130. The above is not what gives the exact error, but the logic is nearly identical. I'll update again to add the only difference, which is the inclusion of a third field in the UK that is always null

Comment: @K_foxer9, Yes, the index is valid.

Comment: Updates made to include third key value to make the logic truly identical. I excluded this because the third field in the UK is always null in my case. I cannot add a default or alter the UK or I would have.

Comment: @Bender The syntax error is the missing closing semicolon, which is required in SQL Server. The fact that you didn't spot it means you never actually executed this bit of SQL yourself.

Comment: And this situation gives you an error? [Still not reproducible](http://rextester.com/ICX59116). Do you have anything else on those tables?

Comment: @hvd I cannot use the exact tables. The above is representative of my current setup.

Comment: @Rigerta, thank you for putting that together. There are more records in each table, but none that match the record causing the issue. There are more fields in each table, but no other indexes. The merge statement is exactly the same as what I have but with the table and field names masked.

Comment: @Bender You don't have to use the exact tables. You certainly can change the table names to `table1` and `table2`, and similar for the column names. It it is your responsibility though to ensure you don't simplify your SQL so much that it can no longer be used to reproduce the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This might be a long shot and maybe not even the actual problem you have, but [there's a case when MERGE statement incorrectly reports unique key violations](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/). There used to be a Connect item on it but unfortunately the Connect website is not available anymore.

Comment: Well that is good to know. 

It's not the problem I had. I'm just a dummy. Hours into this project, I'm a little too close to it and was wrong about my current setup. In table 2, I had: (0, 1, 2, 3, null) and another record (0, 1, 3, 3, null). So the merge was working correctly and trying to update 2 records. The business rules say that can't happen and it shouldn't have been allowed to, so I was working under that assumption when checking for dups. Thanks for the help. Sorry this wasn't a more interesting problem.

Comment: Haha great you found out the actual problem! :)